# Excel: STDEV of Matching Array

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to compute the standard deviation of each set of data corresponding to a different test in Excel. Given a data set like this:

```
Test #  |  Data
   1        0.2
   1        0.3
   1        0.2
   2        0.5
   2        0.6
   3        0.9
   3        0.8
   3        0.8
```

How can I come up with this output in other cells:

```
Test #  |  Std dev of Data
   1             X
   2             Y
   3             Z
```

Where X is the standard deviation of Test 1 data: (0.2, 0.3, 0.2), Y is the standard deviation of Test 2 data, etc.

Ideally the solution will use all built-in Excel functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried Pivot table? The StdDev function is also available there.

[image]

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! I had never heard of Pivot tables before.